# Synchronous mode of USART

Tags: c, synchronous, stm32, usart

I am working with stm32f103 and I want to send and receive data with synchronous mode of USART2. So I have a question, how can I set the clock for example to 10 MHZ for USART?
Which register?

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;                    

RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd( RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA | RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO ,ENABLE);
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART2,ENABLE);                                       

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;               
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;         
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_10MHz;       
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);                  

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_3; 
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IPU;                       
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_4;               
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;         
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_10MHz;       
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;

USART_ClockInitTypeDef USART_ClkInitStructure;                        

USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate            = 4390 ;              
USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength          = USART_WordLength_8b;    
USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits            = USART_StopBits_1;       
USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity              = USART_Parity_No ;       
USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode                = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx; 
USART_Init(USART2, &USART_InitStructure);                               
USART_ITConfig(USART2,USART_IT_RXNE,ENABLE);                            
__nop(); __nop();

USART_ClkInitStructure.USART_Clock=USART_Clock_Enable;
USART_ClkInitStructure.USART_CPOL=USART_CPOL_Low;
USART_ClkInitStructure.USART_CPHA=USART_CPHA_2Edge;
USART_ClkInitStructure.USART_LastBit=USART_LastBit_Enable;
USART_ClockInit(USART2, &USART_ClkInitStructure);

USART_Cmd(USART2, ENABLE);
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the examples provided with the STM32 standard library?

Comment: yes i checked several examples but all of them worked on asynchronous mode and i couldnt find anything about clock setting.

Comment: Check the stm32 standard library example: STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Lib_V3.5.0/Project/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Examples/USART/Synchronous

Comment: Thank you so much. I checked it too and was helpful but there wasnt any setting about frequency clock . i think i found the solution . there is a prescaler for APB1 and i changed it to reach 9MHZ clock for APB1(or PCLK1). BUT there is a big problem. my usart2 clock pin shows 200 to 400 HZ!!!! in any case. why is wrong even when i use default clock(36MHZ)???

Comment: What is your problem exactly? The baud rate of the USART is not the same as the clock of the bus (APB1 in your case) to which it is connected. Did you set the baud-rate correctly?

Comment: my problem is the clock frequency is wrong in oscilloscope .The default clock frequency for usart2 is 36MHZ but when i checked clock pin (PA4) with oscilloscope it showed a wrong number.i wrote my code in the below. what can be wrong?

Comment: Are you using an internal or an external crystal for your main clock? For external crystals you need to set a macro so that the STM32 library knows its frequency, did you do that?

Comment: I used development board SZWB-sail STM32f103VET6 KIT v3.1 . it has 2 crystal on board joint to micro .the 8 MHZ that joint to OSC_IN and OSC_OUT pin and 32.768KHZ that joint to PC14 and PC15.And my sysclk is 72MHZ.

Comment: Please try the code with the change from "GPIO_Speed_10MHz" to "GPIO_Speed_50MHz". Also why did you set RX pin to "Input pull up"? Don't you want "input floating"?

Comment: Also 4390 is a very unusual baud rate, can you try with standard values like 4800 or 9600?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the example provided in the STM32 standard peripheral library (located in STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Lib_V3.5.0/Project/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Examples/USART/Synchr‌​onous)

The two important lines in your case are:

```
USART_ClockInitStructure.USART_Clock = USART_Clock_Enable;
```

and:

```
USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 115200;
```

In your code, you should replace:

```
GPIO_Speed_10MHz
```

by:

```
GPIO_Speed_50MHz
```

Comment: Yes i used this two lines in my code.but when i checked clock pin with oscilloscope it was not 36 MHZ as default.it is my problem.

Comment: i need this clock pin to join it to a sensor to get data from it by usart2.

Comment: Which baud rate do you want to use? Why do you expect 36 MHz?

Comment: My baud rate is 4390. so what is default clock of usart2 if its not 36MHZ?

Comment: What do you mean with default clock? The usart2 clock should always correspond to the baud rate which is currently configured for usart2.

Comment: oh wait...you mean clock corresponds to baud rate and determined by baud rate? and shouldn't set lonely ? so what is PCLK1=maximum 36MHZ? does it correspond to 4.5Mbit (maximum baud rate)?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, PCLK1 is only the frequency of the bus on which the USART is, there are some dividers between PCLK1 and the clock of the USART.

Comment: ok ,so how the clock pin has been determined in synchronous mode?

Comment: The usart clock speed is determined by the baud rate, you should read the USART part from the STM32's reference manual: http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00171190.pdf

Comment: hi Étienne ,I changed my code using what you suggested to me . And when i test it i find my usart2_ck pin in always about 2.4 MHZ (in oscilloscope)and it didnt change with baud rate. if what you said is right ,usart clock pin must changes with baud rate but it didnt happen. and i read that manual again and again . There was not anything about clock setting just ( fck/16*USARTDIV = TX/RX baude rate ) and PCLK1 is maximum 36MHZ for usart2 and PCLK2 is maximum 72 MHZ for usart1.

Comment: how can i determine usart2_ck in synchronous mode? i used 4800 and 9600 baude rate but usart2_ck was always about 2.4 MHZ in oscilloscope.

Comment: Can you try the example from the standard library and see if it works on your board? Then make one change at a time until it stops working.

Comment: yes, my board had a problem and i fixed it. so i changed the baud rate and saw changes, it worked till 12 MHZ . Is it correct? but question is unsolved yet. how it determined ??

Comment: I found the answer, clock frequency(CK pin) in synchronous mode and  Baud rate are the same.